# ASP .NET : Drawing charts sequential after page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-webpages, dotnethighcharts

I am drawing multiple charts from code behind in asp.net web forms page.
in each method to draw chart i call database and retrieve data then draw the chart which take along time to complete all charts.
If i did it in page load event the page still loading untill all charts drawn.
Is there away to load page and then draw each chart sequential without still loading and blocking the page?
I use dot net Highchart library to draw charts as example in below link

[Dot Net High Charts](https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Take a look at this: [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)

Comment: I tried the example in this link but still get the same result.Load method complete execution .However page still blocked and loading